# state not reflected in child component but its printed in console

Tags: reactjs

Good Evening,

Actually I push the documents details into an array , and set that array to state , likewise I set 4 states like this. but state value is not rendering on child component but console print the value.

```
console.log(array1); //print in parent component 
    let array2 = array1;
    setData1(array2);

<child data1={data1} />
```

Child Component code is

```
function child({ data1 }) {
console data1; // print value perfectly
return(
<>
<ul>
{
data1.map((data) => {
return(<li>{data.name}</li> )
})
}
</ul>
</>
);
}
export default child;
```

if data have 5 index ,

shows sometimes 2 index , sometime 3 , and sometime nothing to show.

```
sample data
data = [
{'name': 'aaa'},
{'name' : 'bbb'},
{'name': 'ccc'}
]
```

even I used useEffect with dependency of this data.length nothing works.
Let me know, what is the issue.
Thanks

Comment: You need to return the value inside map using the `return` keyword like `data1.map((data) => {
 return <li>{data.name}</li> 
})
}` . Or else you can use like `data1.map((data) => (<li>{data.name}</li>)`

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that when i compress the code , I already doing like this only , I updated my code now , Please check

Comment: Could you please add the value you get in `data1` in the question ?

Comment: I added sample data @ManirajMurugan

Comment: Try optional chaining `?` to avoid undefined value of data1 like `data1?.map.......` . Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-kgsyxc

Comment: @ManirajMurugan still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Child component: add return to map

```
function child({ data1 }) {
      console data1; // print value perfectly
      return(
          <>
            <ul>
               {
                data1.map((data) => {
                   return(
                   <li>{data.name}</li>
                   ) 
                })
              }
          </ul>
         </>
      );
      }
export default child;
```

Comment: Sorry @Ingenious, when i compress the code i missed that return , now i edited it , even i used return that not showing always and all values